# Managing Navigation Controller Hierarchy stack back button? Unwind?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, storyboard

I have a single page app that has a UISearchTableViewController with an embedded UINavigationController which segues to UIHomeViewController that has two buttons.

From there, I want both buttons to segue into the same UIHomeSelectorViewController with an embedded UINavigationController which can then be able to traverse back into the UIHomeViewController of the previous and back again to the UISearchTableViewController.

I've been trying to use storyboard reference to organize my UIHomeSelectorViewController in a seperate file. But when I link up between UIHomeViewController and UIHomeSelectorViewController. I don't get a `<back` link in my navigation bar. Is there a reason why I'm not able to do this?

I want a way to be able to traverse back to the first UISearchTableViewController How can I do this?

[UISearchTableViewController]-->[UIHomeViewController]-->[UIHomeSelectorViewController]-->[UICollectionViewController]

I appreciate your help! Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to do this by embedding UISearchTableViewController into a UINavigationController and pushing/popping the other view controllers on/off the navigation stack

Comment: can you post your code?